# Pass touch event to view's parent in react native.

Tags: react-native, touch-event

I have a `<view>` touching which will open a collapsible view. I have used react-native-collapse-view for it (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-collapse-view) I have `<text>` on top of `<view>` which is covering it full. I am setting some conditions in `onPress` event of the `<text>` element.

Now what I want is if I touch the `<text`> (obviously I cannot touch view as text is covering it fully), along with `onPress` event of the `<text>` the underlaying `<view>` should also be touched so that it opens the collapsible view.

In short I want to pass the touch event to the parent view in order to complete all work in one touch. I searched and found some content related to `onStartShouldSetResponder` and `pointerEvents` but I couldn't get the complete grip as I am a newbie to react native.

Comment: can you trigger the event with something like redux and have the action do what you need?
another thing if you can is to send from the parent to the child a function (like @dbvt10), can you?
I think with more context we could reply better, can you give a snippet of the code?

Answer (score -1):

in short you need pass function to children for handling events

```
import React from "react";

class ChildComponent extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    const {handleChildPress} = this.props;
    return <Text onPress={handleChildPress}/>;
  }
}

class ContainerComponent extends React.PureComponent {

  // you need pass this func to children
  // =()=> means  bind it
  handleChildPress=()=>{
     console.log('child pressed')
  }

  render() {
    return <ChildComponent handleChildPress={this.handleChildPress}/>;
  }
}



export default ContainerComponent
```